# Install prometheus-operator doesn't work on AWS EC2 keeps produce "Error: failed to download "stable/prometheus-operator"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I'm trying to install

```
[ec2-user@ip-*********** ~]$ helm install stable/prometheus-operator --generate-name
Error: failed to download "stable/prometheus-operator" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

And also installing the monitoring doesn't work :

```
helm install monitoring --namespace monitoring stable/prometheus-operator
```

Produces :

```
[ec2-user@ip-&&&&&&&&&&& ~]$ helm install monitoring --namespace monitoring
Error: must either provide a name or specify --generate-name

[ec2-user@ip-&&&&&&&&&&& ~]$ helm install monitoring --namespace monitoring --generate-name
Error: failed to download "monitoring" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

you need to add the repo first, and there is updated/latest kube-prometheus-stack (prometheus-operator)

```
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm repo update
helm -n monitoring install [RELEASE_NAME] prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

ref:

- https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 2):

I've installed prometheus more recently than above (may 2021) and it seems that they changed the syntax again. The correct commands is as below, so I think it might help if you want to install it now:

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
helm repo update
helm install [pod name] prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

Comment: If you don't have any specific Pod name, we can give generate name 
 
`helm install  --generate-name prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`

Comment: `stable/prometheus-operator ` no longer valid. Use `helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are slightly missing the syntax: try

```sh
helm install --name prometheus --namespace monitoring stable/prometheus-operator
```

Here `--name` mean name of helm deployment, and `stable/prometheus-operator` is helm chart to be used.

Comment: `stable/prometheus-operator` - deprecated, use instead `prometheus-community` chart.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed prometheus just yesterday and it seems that they changed the syntax again. Took me an hour to research the correct commands, so I think it might help if you want to install it now - in 2021:

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stabled
helm repo update
helm install [pod name] stable/prometheus
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.